# Returning dates in different format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, if-statement, format

I have made a function in the format: day/month/year. I would like to make another function that asks the user for example: "When do you want to come?" and depending on what month the user say I want to print out a answer.

The problem: I don't know how to make the function that asks the user for the format: day/month/year without limit the years, I would like the user to enter any year and still be able to get the same answers as another any year (but different month).

```
enter code here
import datetime 

def dateformat(date):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(datumet, "%d/%m/%Y")

def ask_user():
    winter = dateformat('1/1/2020') <= dateformat('31/3/2020')
    spring = dateformat('1/4/2020') <= dateformat('31/5/2021')
    summer = dateformat('1/6/2020') <= dateformat('31/9/2021')
    autumn = dateformat('1/10/2020') <= dateformat('31/12/2021')
    
    a = dateformat(input("When do you want to come"))
    if a == winter:
        print("Hi")
    if a == spring:
        print("bye")
    if a == summer:
        print("ok")
    if a == autumn:
        print("no")
```

My question: How can I make this code work for any year? I would like to be able to type any year but inside the month and get the same output. If I only return %d/%m in the dateformat-function the user will not be able to type: day/month/year. Is there maybe a better way of returning the format?

Comment: From the input you can just extract the day and month. This will allow the user to type in any year. Then, this ```If I only return %d/%m in the dateformat-function the user will not be able to type: day/month/year``` will not be a problem. The season does not depend on the year.

Comment: @MacOS how do you mean? How can I make winter all the moths that I had without caring about which year?

Comment: I don't think your code does what you expect it to do. For one, `31/9/2021` is not an actual date so `dateformat` would throw an error. Second, `winter`, `spring`, etc. are booleans. You're essentially comparing a date to a boolean, so they'll never be equal and you won't get any output.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Do you have an example? I see what you mean.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi How can I make winter for example: 01/12<= 31/3, but make the user type the year too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your code does what you expect it to do. For one, `31/9/2021` is not an actual date so `dateformat` would throw an error. Second, `dateformat('1/1/2020') <= dateformat('31/3/2020')` checks if the first date is less than or equal to the second, so `winter`, `spring`, etc. are booleans (and all `True`). With `a == winter`, you're comparing a date to a boolean, so they'll never be equal and you won't get any output.

What you *actually* want to do is read in the date, and see if its `month` attribute is between certain limits, because the value of `a.year` doesn't affect the season. So:

```
datumet = input("When do you want to come? ")
a = datetime.datetime.strptime(datumet, "%d/%m/%Y")
if a.month <= 3:
    print("Hi, you're coming in winter")
elif a.month <= 5:
    print("Spring")
elif a.month <= 9:
    print("Summer")
else:
    print("Autumn")
```

The same applies when your ranges don't end at the end of the year. For example, if winter lasted the start of November through the end of February,

```
if a.month >= 11 or a.month <= 2:
    print("Hi, you're coming in winter")
elif a.month <= 5:
    print("Spring")
elif a.month <= 9:
    print("Summer")
else:
    print("Autumn")
```

Comment: @Carl-ErikPettersson https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwPXM.png Can you elaborate? It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Sorry! I typed wrong! But I noticed one thing, the code wont work with for-loops, I created a list with numbers and would like to make it all printed out when a specific month gets called but it didnt work. It only gave me the first element in the list

Comment: I can show you how I mean by editing my orginal question check it please :)

Comment: Do that. I'm not sure what you mean, so seeing your code will help.

Comment: never mind I wrote wrong again! Thanks again sir!! :)))

Comment: Do you know how I can fix error handling? I get: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime when trying

Comment: `strptime` wants the first argument to be a string, because the function _parses a string_ into a datetime object. If you don't want that error, give it a string, not a `datetime` object.

Comment: I see, but the user is supposed to type: date/month/year

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225334/discussion-between-pranav-hosangadi-and-carl-erik-pettersson).

Comment: Do you have time to discuss today? I finished what you told me to do and need to do the same thing but using tkinkter

Comment: Sir I have one question. Do you rember when you did the code for writing files for one year. My question: is it possible to do the exactly same thing but to write the files from the day I run the program then one year forward? Instead of the current year?

Comment: Yes it is. Unfortunately I'm not able to provide free personalized python support. Like I said in our chat the other day, you should take some time to understand our discussion, think carefully about what you need to do and how you'll implement it. Step through the code I gave you to see what each line does, that will help you understand the code better. If you run into problems, ask another question about that specific problem. If I see it later, I'll try to write an answer.

Comment: I see sir. I wrote:                         
    current_year = dtm.date.today().year 
    the_year = datetime(current_year, 1, 1)                                                                  According to our chat I think that I should change the datetime(current_year, #Something, #Something) but the "something" I have no idea of what to put